# The distribution function associated with a Borel measure (Folland Theorem 1.16)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

Here is Theorem 1.16 page 35 from Folland's Real Analysis.
[image: Folland Theorem 1.16 page 35]

I don't quite understand the reverse part of the theorem. When $x<0$, what is $\mu((-x,0])$? Since $-x >0$, how do we define the measure of the interval $(a,0]$, where $a>0$? And why the defined function is the distribution function associated with $\mu$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo. It should simply be $-\mu((x, 0])$ for $x<0$. I believe it's been corrected in later editions (well, it's corrected on the Kindle edition anyway).

Comment: I thought it was a typo too, but Stein's book defines the distribution function in the same way !!

Comment: @GGG it really is a typo. It's also listed on Folland's website: [Errata to "Real Analysis", 2nd edition (first five printings)](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~folland/Homepage/oldreals.pdf)